# Pandas keeping certain rows based on strings in other rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
+-------+------------+--+
| index |    keep    |  |
+-------+------------+--+
|     0 | not useful |  |
|     1 | start_1    |  |
|     2 | useful     |  |
|     3 | end_1      |  |
|     4 | not useful |  |
|     5 | start_2    |  |
|     6 | useful     |  |
|     7 | useful     |  |
|     8 | end_2      |  |
+-------+------------+--+
```

There are two pairs of strings (`start_1`, `end_1`, `start_2`, `end_2`) that indicate that the rows between those strings are the only ones relevant in the data. Hence, in the dataframe below, the output dataframe would be only composed of the rows at index 2, 6, 7 (since 2 is between start_1 and end_1; and 6 and 7 is between start_2 and end_2)

```
d = {'keep': ["not useful", "start_1", "useful", "end_1", "not useful", "start_2", "useful", "useful", "end_2"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

What is the most Pythonic/Pandas approach to this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do that (in a couple of steps, for clarity). There might be others:

```
df["sections"] = 0
df.loc[df.keep.str.startswith("start"), "sections"] = 1
df.loc[df.keep.str.startswith("end"), "sections"] = -1
df["in_section"] = df.sections.cumsum()
res = df[(df.in_section == 1) & ~df.keep.str.startswith("start")]
```

Output:

```
   index    keep  sections  in_section
2      2  useful         0           1
6      6  useful         0           1
7      7  useful         0           1
```

Comment: True. The result of a copy-paste. Will change.